# Изменение вида численной строки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

У меня есть блок `div` и `input`. Когда пользователь вводит значение в `input`, то это значение переносится в `div`. Как мне сделать, что бы когда пользователь вводил, к примеру степень ( `2^3` ), то она в `div'е` отображалась вот так: `2³` ?

Код:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#number').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#value').html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="text" id="number">
</p>
<p>Уравнение:</p>
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: `$('#value').html(process($(this).val()));`, где process - ваше преобразование

Comment: @vp_arth, а что за `process`?

Comment: Функция вида `string => string`, в которой вы парсите значение поля, и строите то, что хотите увидеть.

Comment: @vp_arth, так я и не пойму как это запарсить и вывести то что хочу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#value').html(process($(this).val()));`, где `process` - ваше преобразование:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#number').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#value').html(process($(this).val()));
  });
});

function process(str) {
  return str.replace(/\^(\d+)/g, '<sup>$1</sup>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="text" id="number">
</p>
<p>Уравнение:</p>
<div id="value"></div>
```

---

В `Javascript` нет поддержки рекурсирных регулярных выражений, поэтому нужно либо писать парсер, либо извращаться.
Без вложенных скобок можно так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#number').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#value').html(process($(this).val()));
  });
  $('#value').html(process($('#number').val()));
});

function process(str) {
  var res;
  while (res !== str) {
    res = str;
    str = res.replace(
      /([^+\-*/\^()]+)\^([^+\-*/\^()]+|\([^\)]+\))/g, 
      '$1<sup>$2</sup>'
    );
  }
  return str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="text" id="number" value="a^(x^3+3^x)/x^2">
</p>
<p>Уравнение:</p>
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: А если я введу 2^(3^5), то не выведет

Comment: Я не планирую писать за вас парсер выражений. Простите.

Comment: Спасибо. Додумал. Никогда не дружил с регулярными выражениями :)